# LU Decomposition

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-decomposition

i did an exercise with LU decomposition in Matlab, my professor highlighted some problems, but i don't understand what i should correct.

This is for the lower triangular matrix:

```
function b = triI(A,b)
   n = length(A);
   for i=1:n
     for j=1:i-1
       b(i) = b(i) - A(i,j)*b(j);
     end
   if A(i,i) == 0
       error(’the matrix is singular’)
   end
   b(i) = b(i)/A(i,i);
end
```

This is for the lower triangular matrix:

```
 function b = triS(A,b)
   n = length(A);
   for i=n:-1:1
     for j=i+1:n
       b(i) = b(i) - A(i,j)*b(j);
     end
   if A(i,i) == 0
       error(’the matrix is singular’)
   end
   b(i) = b(i)/A(i,i);
end
```

LU decomposition

```
function x = solveLU(A,x)
 n = lenght(A);
 M = tril(A,-1)+eye(n);
 x = solvetril(M,x);
 M = triu(A);
 x = solvetriu(M,x);
```

How can i resolve this? He said that it isn't a correct algorithm...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the problems that your professor highlighted?

Comment: He didn't say nothing... He has only highlighted all the exercise on the LU decomposition... :(

Comment: Unfortunately you aren't performing the LU decomposition properly.  All you're doing is splitting up the matrix `A` into upper and lower triangular.  LU has an additional property where when you multiply `L` and `U` together, you should get `A`.  Indeed that `L` and `U` are lower and upper triangular matrices, but you must make sure that `LU = A`.  What you are doing in your `solveLU` code is not the case.  You've got the **general algorithm** to solve for a system using `LU` correct, but not the actual decomposition itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, how can i resolve this problem?